# elastic search primary key and secondary key

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elastics search with products. Every product has an article number in the form of a guid. To show this products on a webshop I don't want to show a guid (to long). I want an integer number.

Now i have two keys. One to lookup the web request (the integer) and one to update the product (the guid)

I know I can search on a field in elastic search. But is an exact match search on a field slower as an exact match on a key (_id)? I don't want to do a mapping search from one key to the other because that is another operation.

Comment: Can you please explain your question with example..

Comment: I want to know if exact searching on _id is just as fast as searching on a field in the source?

Answer (score 3):

The `_id` field is just a primary key for documents. It will be stored separately. Yes, there will be some lag. But you'll find it's not that much lag. If you want a field to search as fast as `_id` field. Then in mapping, store the field externally. Refer to [the store attribute for a field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string).

Like other fields, it's also stored in ES. By default `_id` is not analyzed. If you define a field as `not_analyzed` its also as fast as the `_id` field. ES indexes each and every field the same.